# search element with dynamic ID using java htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

From a web page, I want to search all h3 whose id starts with `'Tomcat_'` and ends with `'_released'`

```
<h3 id="Tomcat_9.0.19_Released">
  <span class="pull-right">
    2019-04-13
  </span>
   Tomcat 9.0.19 Released
</h3>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

first:
[excample](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/web-scraping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java)

```
DomNodeList<DomElement> ss = page.getElementsByTagName("h3");
```

and later:
[excample](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/web-scraping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/URLContent.java)

```
String value = temp.getAttribute("id");

if(value.startsWith("Tomcat_")&value.endsWith("_released")){
System.out.println(value);
}
```